# FastAPI Writing a multi-line .md file based on inputs

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to write a Python script using FastAPI to accept API data similar to:
`/incidents/?t=sometitle&d=somedescription`

That will then create a `.md` file using this as data.

I've got as far as this:

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/incidents/{incident_id}")
def read_item(incident_id: int, t: Optional[str] = None, d: Optional[str] = None):
    # return {"incident_id": incident_id, "t": t, "d": d}
    # Should be available at:  http://localhost:8000/incidents/5?t=sometitle
    outputFileName = incident_id + "-" + t + ".md"

    l1 = "---"
    l2 = "title:" + t
    l3 = "description:" + d
    l4 = "---"

    with open(outputFileName,'w') as out:
        out.write('{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(l1,l2,l3,l4))
```

But I'm running into some issues with getting the actual file writing part working.

In a seperate `.py` I can get this working:

```
outputFileName = "file" + ".md"

l1 = "---"
l2 = "title:" + "Test Title"
l3 = "description:" + "Test Description"
l4 = "---"

with open(outputFileName,'w') as out:
    out.write('{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(l1,l2,l3,l4))
```

But I can't work out how to get this to work inside my FastAPI `main.py`

If anyone has any pointers I'd be greatful!

Comment: Warning: Your code is vulnerable to path injection. Consider the case when `t = '/../'` you could use this to arbitrarily modify the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I was totally over-thinking this.
There's probably a better way of doing this than **THIS** but for now this works:

```
@app.get("/incidents/{incident_id}")
def read_item(incident_id: int, title: Optional[str] = None, description: Optional[str] = None):

    f = open("demofile.md", "a")
    f.write("---" + "\n" + "title: " + title + "\n" + "description: " + description + "\n" + "---")
    f.close()
```